# cmake gives an error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I try to install a library, I am getting the following error messages:

Make Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:55 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CXX:

g++-5.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)

CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /localscratch/safa/ompl-1.2.1-Source/build/Release/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /localscratch/safa/ompl-1.2.1-Source/build/Release/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/localscratch/safa/ompl-1.2.1-Source/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No rule to make target `update_bindings'.  Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target`install'.  Stop.

Can you suggest me any solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the c++ compiler ?

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```